# How to create a control like this?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a control like this. 
[Click on this link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr6ea.png)

How to do that ?

I got some help to start with. But, still not sure how to do it.

In xaml I have something like this:

```
<Grid Background="White"
      MouseUp="ParentOnMouseUp">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" 
            Background="Green"
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            MouseMove="CanvasOnMouseMove">

            <Ellipse x:Name="dot"
                 Width="20"
                 Height="20"
                 Fill="Blue"
                 Loaded="DotOnLoaded"
                 MouseDown="DotOnMouseDown"/>
    </Canvas>
```

In the code behind file I have the following code

```
private void DotOnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _isDraggingDot = true;

}


private void CanvasOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isDraggingDot)
    {
        var mousePos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

        var x = mousePos.X;
        if (x < 0)
        {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (x > canvas.Width)
        {
            x = canvas.Width;
        }

        var y = mousePos.Y;
        if (y < 0)
        {
            y = 0;
        }
        if (y > canvas.Height)
        {
            y = canvas.Height;
        }

        dot.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x - (dot.Width / 2.0)); // offset ensures dot is centred on mouse pointer
        dot.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y - (dot.Height / 2.0));
    }
}



private void ParentOnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _isDraggingDot = false;
    //CentreDot();
}/


private void CentreDot()
{
    dot.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (canvas.Width / 2.0) - (dot.Width / 2.0));
    dot.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (canvas.Height / 2.0) - (dot.Height / 2.0));
}


private void DotOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CentreDot();

}
```

I am not able to draw the horizontal scale of -180 to +180 and the vertical scale of -30 to +30. Also, once the dot is moved to a specific point. I need the co-ordinates of that point.

Comment: In wpf the thing that's designed to be dragged is called a thumb. You can template that as anything you like. Including an ellipse. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/393ac5/thumb-class-in-wpf74/

Comment: If you put the canvas in a grid and gave that grid 2 columns and to rows then you could put textblocks in the grid.column, grid.row for the numbers. Use horizontal and vertical alignment to shift them to one end of whichever cell (but they're not really a cell) you put them in.